# Monitoring Azure Virtual Hard Disks

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have attached multiple Unmanaged disks to an Azure VM. I have enabled the diagnostics for this VM. Is there a way I can get the metrics for each of the attached disks ?

Comment: What metrics are you referring to?

Comment: The Latency metric and the Disk Read and Write Metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get the metrics for each of the attached disks ?

Yes, it is possible. You could use Linux Diagnostic Extension to monitor metrics.  The Linux Diagnostic Extension helps a user monitor the health of a Linux VM running on Microsoft Azure. It has the following capabilities:

> Enables users to customize the data metrics that are collected and
>   uploaded.

More information please refer to this link:[Use Linux Diagnostic Extension to monitor metrics and logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/diagnostic-extension).

What you need to do is modify your new disk to `PublicConfig.json`. Just add following lines to this file.

```
  {
            "annotation": [
              {
                "displayName": "Disk /dev/sdc1", 
                "locale": "en-us"
              }
            ], 
            "class": "disk", 
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
            "counter": "readbytespersecond", 
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/FreeSpace(/newdisk)", 
            "type": "builtin", 
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
          },
```

More information about this, you could check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44527724/monitoring-using-azure-linux-diagnostics).