# Monitoring using Azure Linux Diagnostics

Tags: linux, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk

I am trying to enable Linux Diagnostics for individual disks attached to the VM. I am referring to this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/diagnostic-extension)

I am using this CLI

```
azure vm extension set vmturbo DiagnosticTest LinuxDiagnostic Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics '3.0' --private-config-path PrivateConfig.json --public-config-path PublicConfig.json -v
```

And this is how PrivateConfig.json looks like

```
    {
        "storageAccountName" : “XXXXXXXXXX”,
        "storageAccountSasToken": "sv=2016-05-31&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2017-06-13T19:34:34Z&st=2017-06-13T11:34:34Z&spr=https,http&sig=G%2FXj0rYHNk7jUx6CF47kPdJh42jhafSsUvT0JlrR3XE%3D"
    }

And this is how PublicConfig.json looks like 
{
  "StorageAccount": "diagnosticvmstorage",
  "sampleRateInSeconds": 15,
  "ladCfg": {
    "diagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {
      "performanceCounters": {
        "sinks": "",
        "performanceCounterConfiguration": [
         {
          {
            "annotation": [
              {
                "displayName": "Disk write time", 
                "locale": "en-us"
              }
            ], 
            "class": "disk", 
            "condition": "Name=\"/dev/sdc1\"",
            "counter": "averagewritetime", 
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/averagewritetime", 
            "type": "builtin", 
            "unit": "Seconds"
          }, 
          {
            "annotation": [
              {
                "displayName": "Filesystem transfers/sec", 
                "locale": "en-us"
              }
            ], 
            "class": "filesystem", 
            "condition": "Name=\"/newdisk\"",
            "counter": "transferspersecond", 
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/filesystem/transferspersecond", 
            "type": "builtin", 
            "unit": "CountPerSecond"
          }
        ]
      },
      "metrics": {
        "metricAggregation": [
          {
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1H"
          },
          {
            "scheduledTransferPeriod": "PT1M"
          }
        ],
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/758ad253-cbf5-4b18-8863-3eed0825bf07/resourceGroups/vmturbo/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/DiagnosticTest"
      },
      "eventVolume": "Large"
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

The VM has a disk attached to it /dev/sdc1 and it is mounted at /newdisk. Even after using both the performanceCounters I still don't see any data in the WADMetrics***** table. Is there anything which I am doing wrong or am I missing out anything in the config file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: this question is perfectly fine here in my opinion

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Out of morbid curiosity... Do you feel the site's rules allow it; or do you feel the site's rules don't apply to you?

Comment: @jww what does it have to do with me? its not my question. and if you don't understand how this is about programming and not linux administration is beyond me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/diagnostic-extension#public-settings) that you provided, you need modify `counterSpecifier` not `condition`. Please refer below:

> The counterSpecifier is an arbitrary identifier. Consumers of metrics,
>   like the Azure portal charting and alerting feature, use
>   counterSpecifier as the "key" that identifies a metric or an instance
>   of a metric. For builtin metrics, we recommend you use
>   counterSpecifier values that begin with /builtin/. If you are
>   collecting a specific instance of a metric, we recommend you attach
>   the identifier of the instance to the counterSpecifier value. Some
>   examples:

- `/builtin/Processor/PercentIdleTime` - Idle time averaged across all
  cores
- `/builtin/Disk/FreeSpace(/mnt)` - Free space for the /mnt filesystem
- `/builtin/Disk/FreeSpace` - Free space averaged across all mounted
  filesystems

I test in my lab, you could modify your json file as below:

```
   {
            "annotation": [
              {
                "displayName": "Disk /dev/sdc1", 
                "locale": "en-us"
              }
            ], 
            "class": "disk", 
            "condition": "IsAggregate=TRUE", 
            "counter": "readbytespersecond", 
            "counterSpecifier": "/builtin/disk/FreeSpace(/newdisk)", 
            "type": "builtin", 
            "unit": "BytesPerSecond"
          },
```

[image]

Notes: I test on a ARM Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I use `az vm extension set --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics --name LinuxDiagnostic --version 3.0 --resource-group $my_resource_group --vm-name $my_linux_vm --protected-settings "${my_lad_protected_settings}" --settings portal_public_settings.json` to enable LAD.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. Appreciate it. I hope there was also a way that Azure monitors each of the new disk added otherwise I have to update performanceCounterConfiguration manually each time a user adds a new disk.

Comment: Currently, it is not possible. I suggest you could use a script to add lines to public.json.